# How can I make the directory writable, permanently, without having to run the command again?

Tags: linux, jenkins, playframework, debian

I have a problem with making /dao permanently writable. I use this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/project/newproject/target/scala-2.11/classes/dao
```

I am using Play-Framework. But when I run activator, the command delete the directory "dao" and create a new one.

I am working with Debian and trying start a bash file in Jenkins to create the Project on a Server

Comment: have you tried "chmod -R 777 /opt/project/newproject/"?

Comment: `umask 777` && activator

Comment: You're not supposed to write into this directory. If you need to write to some file, then choose something else (ie. nothing in `target/`).